# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont.addNewFamily()

Tags: java, apache-poi

Upgraded poi to version and added the jar bundle from apache site. However getting below error :

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont.addNewFamily()
```

However verified that the `JAR` is available in the project and accessible via code too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Version `5.0.0` of `apache poi` cannot use `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` anymore. It needs `poi-ooxml-lite...jar` or `poi-ooxml-full...jar`. So make sure there is not  `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` in class path when `apache poi 5.0.0` is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per comments from @axel which worked, posting it as an answer for better reach.

Version `5.0.0` of apache poi cannot use `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` anymore.

It needs `poi-ooxml-lite...jar` or `poi-ooxml-full...jar`. So make sure there is not `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` in class path when `apache poi 5.0.0` is used

Comment: This worked me perfectly. Was Struggling since 2 days. Thank you Bhavik Patel and @Axel Richter